# How to stop sounds with MediaPlayer c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, audio, media-player, desktop

I have this functions and I must use MediaPlayer because I have to play more sounds together. This code works, but the sounds doesn't stop on the keyup (I tried some code but didn't worked). How can I do the function stopSound?
Thank'you!

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    [...]   // Other code
    playSound(key, name);
}

private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    [...]   // Other code
    stopSound(key, name);
}

private void playSound(string name)
{
    [...]   // Other code
    string url = Application.StartupPath + "\\notes\\" + name + ".wav";
    var sound = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();

    sound.Open(new Uri(url));
    sound.play();
}

private void stopSound(string name)
{
    ???
}
```

Comment: Check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.stop(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Of course, that code works. but now I had to change the code above (due to threads) so your code is not working anymore. Check out my last question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store all references to the `MediaPlayer` instances that you create in a `List<MediaPlayer>`, you could access them later using this list and stop them. Something like this:

```
List<System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer> sounds = new List<System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer>();
private void playSound(string name)
{
    string url = Application.StartupPath + "\\notes\\" + name + ".wav";
    var sound = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
    sound.Open(new Uri(url));
    sound.play();
    sounds.Add(sound);
}

private void stopSound()
{
    for (int i = sounds.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        sounds[i].Stop();
        sounds.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```